# Good hands-on references for VS2010 with NSight 3.0 performance analyzer/profiler

Tags: cuda, nsight

I just wonder if anyone could suggest some good references for some hands on tutorials for NSight 3.0 on VS2010 (well, or some closest version)

The user doc is informative indeed but something more instructional will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GTC2013 Talk *S3382 - Profiling and Optimizing CUDA Kernel Code with NVIDIA Nsight
Visual Studio Edition* describes how to use and interpret the Nsight VSE CUDA Profiler reports.

The majority of the talk is a live demo of profiling (some trace information). The PDF provides very little information.

- [View Recording](http://nvidia.fullviewmedia.com/gtc2013/0321-230C-S3382.html)
- [View PDF](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3382-Profiling-Optimizing-CUDA-Nsight-VSE.pdf)